# Forecasting sales using Neural Network with just 6 data points?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, small-sample

I have 6 data points which represent 6 months of sales of a new product.  Can I use machine learning methods, like a neural network, to forecast the sales of this product over the next year?  Specifically, I want to forecast the cumulative sales volume a year into the future (or at month 18), and project what the sales trend would look like from month 7 to month 18.

If possible, I'd like forecast this trend in R.

Comment: Why would you like to use machine learning here? The answer to your question is NO, of course.

Comment: Is it because it is not feasible or is it because machine learning do not do well with limited data?  They are different.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's difficult to forecast 1 year ahead with only 6 months of data. You don't have data for ML. It works only when you have a ton of training data. With your data you can barely do a naive forecast

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

> Can I use machine learning, like a neural network, to forecast the sales of this product over the next year?

Yes - you can used neural networks, or some other generic ML method, to forecast sales. NNets have mixed results for time series, using other methods such as SVM or XGboost is not very common.

The are also other methods which are designed specifically for time series, such as ARIMA and Exponential Smoothing.

> If possible, I like to perform the forecasting in R.

There is a package in R, the forecast package, which has many of these methods, including ARIMA, Exponential Smoothing, and some Neural Network models, and it is very easy to use.

.....However,

6 data points is not really enough to use any sophisticated forecasting approach to forecast 7~18 steps ahead, you're better off just using a naive forecast (use the last month of the data as your best guess), or maybe a naive seasonal forecast (use current January to forecast next January, current February to forecast next February, etc...) but even then you need at least 12 months of data, so in your case would have a gap between 7 and 12 and can only forecast from 13 to 18.

Since it is sales data, it is very likely seasonal - so basically, you don't have enough data to forecast anything other than a seasonal naive of month 13 ~ 18.

Comment: Thanks! I know I could use a simple regression like y=a+b*t, where t is the period.  Then ARIMA would be like advanced version of that regression.  I am just trying to see if something more accurate has been developed in the Machine Learning literature, since I am not that familiar with it.  I will review the FORECAST package in R.

Comment: ARIMA with 6 points? It's going to be a total garbage. In the dumbest regression you have 2 parameters to estimate, and with 6 points, it'3 observations per parameter

Comment: @Aksakal  I obviously do not expect to have a super accurate prediction.  I was hoping to get within 15% absolute error?  I hope that's possible.  I have a related question.  How far ahead do you typically forecast relative to the number of datapoints you have for training?  What is the ratio?

Comment: In econometrics it's often said that 4 cycles are necessary for seasonality estimation. Sales data are usually highly seasonal. With 6 months data if you were at a bank, and I was your model risk person, you'd have ZERO chance getting the model approved. I'd recommend to go with expert judgement

Comment: @Aksakal If I have 4 years of monthly data, and I want to forecast next 12 years ahead, would you be more comfortable then?  I understand the length of training data too short.  I am also trying to see whether the length of the forecast period is too long as well.  Thanks again for your inputs!

Comment: 4 years monthly would be a Ok set for short term forecasting with seasonality. The problem with 12 years is that it most likely includes at least one downturn, and you don't have a full business cycle in your data, so you don't know how your sales behave in crisis environment. this could be addressed by augmenting the dataset with relevant external data

Comment: I work in retail sales forecasting. We typically require at least 2 years of data if we want to forecast one year out (we do weekly, so we need 104 weeks history to be able to forecast 52 weeks forward). 2 years is minimum, but ideally you want 4 or 5 years for one year forward. So to @Akaskal point, 6 months (and only 6 data points) won't really get you anywhere. 15% is too optimistic, on my team we consider ourselves very lucky indeed if we achieve 15% accuracy and that is with 104 data points. Getting 15% with 6 data points is not realistic.

Comment: @Alex Thanks for your perspective.  I am talking about 15% forecast accuracy ratio = predicted/actual at last period.  I am using cumulative sales, since mine is a new product.  What exactly is your metric, if you don't mind sharing that?

Comment: @K.Lee our metric is the MAPE - Mean Absolute Percent Error - we forecast for a period, then we wait for the actuals for that period to come in, and then we calculate $|\frac{Fcst - Act}{Act}|$ . If we are forecasting for multiple periods forward, we calculate for the average over all future periods $\frac{1}{n}\sum{|\frac{Fcst - Act}{Act}|}$